# Text to be displayed in a single line

Tags: html, css

I need to display a text with a dot and a line before and after the text as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

The text should be displayed in one line. This is the code which I tried:

```css
.before-text:before {
  content: "•";
}

.before-text:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.after-text:before {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.after-text:after {
  content: "•";
}
```

```html
<span class="before-text"></span>
<div>Long long long text</div>
<span class="after-text"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind flex-box and you don't need the exact same code, you can try the following:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.before-text,
.after-text {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.before-text {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.after-text {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.before-text:before,
.after-text:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="before-text"></span>
  <div>Long long long text</div>
  <span class="after-text"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

> You can do this simply with the following code :
>   The after and before pseudo will apply the dots on left and right and text will come in center with position attributes..

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.text--line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.text--line:before {
  content: "•";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.text--line:after {
  content: "•";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.text--line span {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text--line">

  <span>I am text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The line is overlapping the dot.

Comment: the dots will be coming over the line only you can adjust the left and right to -1 or -2px .. that will not be any problem.. this solution is flexible and can work on any device.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with flex?

Comment: you can also just add `background-color: white;padding: 1px 2px;` on the dot to cover the overlapping line

Comment: @athimohan in what sense you are talking about using the flex?

Answer (score 1):

Somethimes I use this:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         span.words::before {content: "•--------"}
         span.words::after {content: "--------•"}
      </style>
   </head>
<body>
   <span class="words">your text here</span>
</body>
</html>
```

But the most probable is that I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, just edit the line that I used

```css
span:before {
  content: "•----------------";
}

span:after {
   content: "----------------•";
}
```

```html
<span>Long long long text</span>
```